# How to remove Crystal Reports database connection in Database Expert

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am trying to remove database connections from the Database Expert of Crystal Reports in VS but the option is grayed out...

I made a lot of connections and now I want to delete them to avoid confusion in My Connections.

Even referred to the [following link](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3206507) but it is useless..

Comment: restart your pc and then try again. Sometimes there is something holding the connections and in use which is why is greyed out. Restarting you machine should free up most unwanted connections.

Comment: Ya, restarting PC works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the `.rpt` file in Visual Studio, and don't do anything, just open `data expert` and `d`, then try to delete the connections by `Right Click` → `Remove Connection`, under `My Connections`, in `Database Expert`.  All connections can be removed, except for those currently used in report.

Answer (score 1):

1. open windows explorer and navigate to C:\Users\yourusername\Documents\History
2. make sure you can view hidden files
3. open each DataSource#.xml file to see which one you want to remove
4. move that file to a different folder (to test)
5. close and reopen your crystal reports application (currently 2016) and check if that removed the expected data source